# php view page based on the search from user

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make the search button to view the page based on what number user will input?

[image]

as you can see in the picture there is **First Page Previous Next Last** the content of the page come from the database

**code:**

```
<ul class="pagination">
<?php if($page_no > 1){
echo "<li><a href='?page_no=1'>First Page</a></li>";
} ?>  
   
<li <?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
<a <?php if($page_no > 1){
echo "href='?page_no=$previous_page'";
} ?>>Previous</a>
</li>
    
<li <?php if($page_no >= $total_no_of_pages){
echo "class='disabled'";
} ?>>
<a <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages) {
echo "href='?page_no=$next_page'";
} ?>>Next</a>
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2" class="box"></li>
<li>
  <button type="submit" class="fa fa-search" style="height:33px;"></button>
</li>
```

means that if user put number 5 i want view page 5

Comment: I think you want that if anyone enter any number you want to redirect to that page. Am I correct

Comment: yes exactly any idea what shall i do

Comment: out of interest what method are you using to achieve the paging? Are you using `limit x,y` or `id between x and y` ? With that many `pages` available performance will be far better with the latter approach afaik

Comment: i used limit for this

Comment: This isn't a php or mysql question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want that if anyone enter any number you want to redirect to that seach page.

**You can use simply use javascript for this work.**

You have to add id to your input field + button.

I am assigning the id to input field as ***search***

I am assigning the id to search button as ***search_btn***

And your javascript goes like this -

```
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const search_btn = document.getElementById('search_btn');

search_btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    let value = search.value;
    location.href = `?page_no=${value}`;
})
```